# How to call a python file that uses flags from another python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, flags

I picked up a script (script1.py) from another dev which uses the flags module from absl. Basically it is ran as such:

```
python script1.py --input1 input1 --input2 input2
```

I currently have another script (script2.py) which generates that input1 and input2 for script1 to run. How can I actually pass the args over to script1 from within script2? I know I have to import script1 but how can I then point it to those inputs?

Comment: you can either use those parameters in function which is being ran, usually `main()` or you can call something like `subprocess` to run the script with `subprocess.Popen()` and pass arguments there.

Comment: It will depend on how the arguments are parsed in `script2.py`. To better answer your question, could you provide more details about the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Python `subprocess` module for this. I am assuming that you are using a version that is 3.5 or newer. In this case you can use the `run` function.

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(
    ['python', 'script1.py', '--input1 input1', '--input2 input2'],
    capture_output=True)

# Get the output as a string
output = result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

Some notes:

1. This example ignores the return code. The code should check `result.returncode` and take correct actions based on that.
2. If the output is not needed, the `capture_output=True` and the last line can be dropped.

The documentation for the `subprocess` module can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

## A alternative (better) solution

A better solution (IMHO) would be to change the called script to be a module with a single function that you call. Then python code in `script1.py` could probably be simplified quite a bit. The resulting code in your script would then be something similar to:

```
from script1 import my_function

my_function(input1, input2)
```

It could be that the script from the other dev already has a function you can call directly.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I will have to give this a try but yeah this makes sense and I think it will work, sadly I myself cannot make changes to script1.py, but I will check with the other dev if it can be updated, as that will simplify this quite a bit.